# TiledMap renders but gets duplicated when I move the camera

Tags: libgdx

I've created a map (TMX file) using Tiled, imported it and it shows great but when I move the camera, it duplicates itself and the whole screen flickers.
In Tiled, I didn't use a spritesheet but rather a collection of images as they have different sizes.

See attached image:
[image]

Here is my game class:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private IsometricTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private TiledMap map;
    private Vector2 dragOld, dragNew;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("isometric_map.tmx");
        renderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 0);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
                    dragNew = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
                    dragOld = dragNew;
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();

        camera.update();

        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            dragNew = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
            if (dragOld != null && !dragNew.equals(dragOld)) {
                camera.translate(((int) dragOld.x - dragNew.x), ((int) dragNew.y - dragOld.y)); //Translate by subtracting the vectors
                camera.update();
                dragOld = dragNew; //Drag old becomes drag new.
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);

        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();

        map.dispose();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you clear the screen? You have to use `glClear()` method to clear the screen before drawing the current frame.

```java
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Hope this helps.